# Aggregation in Single Table Inheritance in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I'm working on Single Table Inheritance in Rails following [this guide](https://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-2/). The classes that I'm working with are as follows:

**Superclass:** Articles
**Subclass:** Tutorials, Projects, Thoughts
*All of them contain 'Comments'*

So I'm able to display all of these articles and filter them by type. However, I have trouble creating a new object of a subclass, say Tutorial.

Here is the snippet of relevant code:

```
#articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def type 
    Article.types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : "Article"
end

def type_class 
    type.constantize 
end

def index
    puts "The type is: " + type
    #@articles = Article.all
    @articles = type_class.all
    @type = type
end

def new
    @article = type_class.new
end

def edit
    @article = type_class.find(params[:id])
end

def show
    @article = type_class.find(params[:id])
end



#show.html.erb
<p>
<strong>Title:</strong>
<%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Text:</strong>
<%= @article.text %>
</p>

<div id="comments">
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>
</div>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Here is my article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
validates :title, presence: true,
length: { minimum: 5 }

scope :projects, -> { where(type: 'Project')}
scope :thoughts, -> { where(type: 'Thought')}
scope :tutorials, -> { where(type: 'Tutorial')}

self.inheritance_column = :type

def self.types
    %w(Tutorial Project Thought)
end

end
```

I'm able to create a new Article object of type Tutorial but when rendering the associated comments, the console displays:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'comments.tutorial_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`tutorial_id` = 29
```

I'm confused as to why the sql query contains `tutorial_id` instead of a plain id. Any suggestions on how to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is reserved by rails, try changing the name of that column to `kind` or `type_of` and see if that fixes the error

Comment: Though not the full answer, this led me on the right track.